# Arranging multiple divs in 2 columns, alternating every 7 divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange divs like the following:

[image: div arrangement]

My php code outputs 7x `<div class="left">` followed by 7x `<div class="right">` then repeats with 7x `<div class="left">` and so on...

I just can't figure out the css. Here is the closest I can get it, but it definitely isn't correct.

```
div.left {
float:left;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 141px;
width: 373px;
}
div.right {
padding-left: 380px;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 141px;
width: 373px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b0mfw7n9/

Here is the PHP code that generates the divs:

```
        <?php 
  if(isset($addresses)) 
    {
    $i=0;
    $state = FALSE; 
    foreach($addresses as $address) 
        { 
if ($i % 7 === 0) {$state = !$state;} ?>
<div class="<?php if ($state) : ?>left<?php else: ?>right<?php endif; ?>"> 
<?php  $i++; ?>
<textarea class="address"><?php echo $address;?></textarea>
</div>
    <?php   } } ?>
```

Comment: Wrap both the dynamic code within new containers and then use float.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the code doing that is incorrect?

Comment: @JohnStrong Adjust the screen size, you can see the alignment problems

Comment: use bootstrap and you dont have to bother about placements. Also your divs are not alternating correctly, please share your php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, adapt it as required and use CSS to change size using media queries

```
<div id=wrapper>
<?php
$i = 1;
$max = 28;
$jump = 8;
$chk = 7;
while($i <$max)
    {
    echo "<div class='border left '> <h1>$i</h1></div>";    
    echo "<div class='border right'><h1>$jump</h1></div>";
        if($i % 7 == 0)
        {
        $i = $i + 7;
        $jump = $jump + 7;
        }
    $i++;   
    $jump++;
    }
?>
</div>
```

and the css

```
div.left {
float:left;
background:#ff3366;
}
div.right {
float:right;
background:#ff6699;
}

textarea.address {
height: 127px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
resize:none;
overflow: auto; 
font-weight: bold; 
font-family: verdana; 
font-size: 16px;
}

.border{
border:1px solid;
min-height:10px;
height: 141px;
width: 375px;
}
#wrapper{
width:755px 

}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned.. the `$addresses` array can vary, and contain up to 100 addresses, sometime more!   

Also the divs must be a fixed size and position because I am generating address labels for printing on A4 sheets containing 14 labels

Comment: set $max to count($addresses)

Comment: to position divs, use the padding and adjust the width. It should work fine, if its just A4  - one size paper

Comment: when i change div from % to px it just gives weird results.   http://i.imgur.com/rJVOLXB.png

Comment: modified the code, any other query please ask on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95103/discussion-between-david-a-and-lucky-chingi).